# How to sum values of multiple inputs using onChange event | ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

I have multiple inputs where user fill these inputs with numbers. I need a way to sum up the values of these inputs when user types in any input.

**My Code**

```
const [values,set_values] = useState({
    sales:'',
    bank_deposit:'',
    supply:'',
    expenses:''
})

const values_handler = (e) => {
    let name= e.target.name;
    let value= e.target.value;
    values[name]=value;
    set_values(values)

    // Calling the method to sum the value
    calc_total(value) 
}

const [total,set_total]=useState(0);

const calc_total = (value) => {
    total +=value;
    set_total(total)
}

<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='sales' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='bank_deposit' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='supply' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='expenses' />
```

**Problem**

The problem with this is that the values are summed up each time the value of an input got a chane, so that if user enters 15, it sums 1 then 5 since the mehtod is executed when a change occurred on the input's value.

Comment: `values[name]=value;` changes state; you're not supposed to do that.

Comment: @ChrisG This to assign the value in its element in values array

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, I'm telling you you're not allowed to do that in React. You need to create a copy of values, change the copy's number, then call `set_values()` passing the copy.

Comment: @ChrisG it would be great if you answer it, so we can benefit from the question, as i searched out how to do this but didn't got a clear answer, so i made this simple question to let everyone understands it. i updated the question with the problem

Comment: Right, you're doing this to help others. The problem here is that your code doesn't even attempt to sum up the values from your actual state. Do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-tdd-mm4xf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you must not mutate the state values.
- state updates are async.
- you need not use the value of each onChange instead use the state values to update total value

Assuming you want to sum sales, bank_deposit, supply and expeses values, you can get them from states do it like below

```
const [values,set_values] = useState({
    sales:'',
    bank_deposit:'',
    supply:'',
    expenses:''
})

const values_handler = (e) => {
    let name= e.target.name;
    let value= e.target.value;
    const newValues = {
        ...values,
        [name]: value
    } 
    set_values(newValues)

    // Calling the method to sum the value
    calc_total(newValues) 
}

const [total,set_total]=useState(0);

const calc_total = (newValues) => {
    const { sales, bank_deposit, expenses, supply} = newValues;
    const newTotal = parseInt(sales) + parseInt(bank_deposit) + parseInt(expenses) + parseInt(supply)
    setTotal(newTotal)

} 

<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='sales' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='bank_deposit' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='supply' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='expenses' />
```

Comment: `calc_total` is adding strings

Comment: Updated my answer, I just left it previously assuming that to not be that important a detail ;-)

Comment: OP wants working code on a silver platter, so why not go the extra mile for them ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const [values,set_values] = useState({
    sales:'',
    bank_deposit:'',
    supply:'',
    expenses:''
})

const values_handler = (e) => {
    let name= e.target.name;
    let value= e.target.value;
    set_values({...values , [name]: value})

// Calling the method to sum the value
calc_total(values) 
}

const [total,set_total]=useState(0);

const calc_total = (values) => {
    aux = 0
    for (var key in values){
        aux += values[key]
    }
    set_total(aux)
}

<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='sales' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='bank_deposit' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='supply' />
<input type='number' onChange={value_handler} name='expenses' />
```

Remarks:
Using Chris G. recommendations in the comments

Comment: `values` isn't an array, for one.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Solution = () => {
  const [input_values, set_inputvalues] = useState({
    sales: 0,
    bank_deposit: 0,
    supply: 0,
    expenses: 0
  });

  const [total, set_total] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const arrValues = Object.values(input_values);
    const inputTotals = arrValues.reduce((accum, curr) => (accum += curr), 0);
    set_total(inputTotals);
  }, [input_values]);

  const changeValues = ({ name, value }) => {
    set_inputvalues({ ...input_values, [name]: parseInt(value) });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{total}</h1>
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={({ target }) => changeValues(target)}
        name="sales"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={({ target }) => changeValues(target)}
        name="bank_deposit"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={({ target }) => changeValues(target)}
        name="supply"
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={({ target }) => changeValues(target)}
        name="expenses"
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

To some up some key gotchas which other's have mentioned:

- Don't alter state directly, use a set_xxx to update state.
- You set type="number" so default state has to be numeric, i.e. sales: 0
- Remember to parse values to int if numeric.